# Return ONLY the matching array and parent fields from a deeply nested document using Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I'm using Mongoose 6.9.0 and MongoDB 6 community, in NestJS 9.

I have a document that's deeply nested:

```json
{
"_id": "63e28016cc763b6cbd436c47",
...otherfields
    "schools": [
        {
            ...otherfields
            "collections": [
                {
                    ...otherfields
                    "projects": [
                        {
                            "slug_name": "a-dolor-numquam453",
                            "pretty_name": "a dolor numquam453",
                            "description": "Laborum expedita facere tenetur voluptatum. Aut tempore non ex fugit hic amet sapiente modi assumenda. Vitae exercitationem quaerat repellat perspiciatis incidunt. In harum consequuntur quisquam. Dolorem dolores mollitia deserunt dolor fugit esse omnis consectetur explicabo.",
                            "owner": null,
                            "data": [
                                {},{},{},{},etc.
                                ],
                            "_id": "63e28017cc763b6cbd437175",
                            "createdAt": "2023-02-07T16:45:15.863Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2023-02-07T16:45:15.863Z"
                        },
                        ...another_project,
                    ]
                },
                ...another_collection,
            ]
        },
        ...another_school,
    ]
}
```

And I want to get:

- Fields from the root document
- Fields from the parent school
- Fields from the parent collection
- Fields from **JUST** the matching project

But my code:

```
findOne(id: string) {
    const objectId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id);
    return this.rootModel.findOne({ 'schools.collections.projects._id': objectId }, { 'schools.collections.projects.$': 1 }).lean().exec();
}
```

Returns every single project in the projects array, including the ones that don't match.

How can I grab just the matching array element (Project), as well as root's fields, school's fields, and collection's fields that the project belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, is this how it should be done?

```
    return this.rootModel
      .aggregate([
        { $unwind: '$schools' },
        { $unwind: '$schools.collections' },
        { $unwind: '$schools.collections.projects' },
        { $match: { 'schools.collections.projects._id': objectId } },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            ...fields: 1,
            'schools....fields': 1,
            'schools.collections....fields': 1,
            'schools.collections.projects': 1,
          },
        },
      ])
      .exec();
```